# reading data from memory in C from within an Objective C class

Tags: objective-c, c, c89

I would like to know if it is possible to read and write data from and to memory with ANSI C code instead of from a file.  I have C code that is called from within an Objective C class many times and each time, it has to read in the same large binary file, do some processing on it, and then write out a large binary file (which is slightly different each time the code is called)

Ideally, I would like to somehow pass the large binary input file from Objective C into the ANSI C code and also pass back the large binary output file from the ANSI C code into Objective C.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something like that if you use [funopen](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/funopen.3.html).

Comment: Can you give a very basic example of how to use funopen?

Answer (score 0):

It's not ANSI, but *gcc* has `fmemopen` and `open_memstream` which may help.

Comment: there is no fmemopen for MacOSX, its linux specific.

Comment: I would have thought that it was glibc specific.